# How to compare multiple collocations based on their Chi2 score? How to find synonyms using collocation analysis

Tags: chi-squared-test, corpus-linguistics

my question is regarding collocation analysis (i'm using R). I have following data gathered from Polish corpus:

```
| collocation | chi2.score  | word.type | count |
|:-----------:|:-----------:|:---------:|:-----:|
| szczególny  | 31501785.92 | baczenie  | 8     |
| chory       |  27.31      | rozum     | 5     |
| pojąć       |  948513.60  | celowo    | 13    |
| odnosić     |  338963.45  | wrazenie  | 1909  |
```

Corpus automatically lists collocates with their Chi2 scores as an association measure. In total there are 66000 rows of data (66000 collocations for 58 unique word.types, each word.type has a different number of significant collocations).

I'm trying to statistically find out which of my word.types has similar collocations as one particular word.type (let's say that it is 'celowo'). Can I actually do anything with these Chi2 scores to compare a pair of word.types' collocations (i.e., using these scores to perform some clustering analysis), or should I focus solely on differences in nominal data column 'collocation'?

More general, though related, question is: having word frequency data and collocations from a linguistic corpus, how would you go about trying to find synonyms/equivalent phrases of a particular word?